# shift data down in one sheet when a new value is entered in a different sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I've reached a point where I'm quite sure I need VBA but I don't know VBA so I need your help. So:

I have a worksheet for organizing data on certain ceramic products.

In my main sheet (called **'Products'**) I enter the name of the product (in column B) and the product number (in column A) along with verious other data `(ex. #101 Brown round plate, #102 Brown square plate, #201 Yellow round plate)`.

In a different sheet (called **'Inventory'**) I have inventory information for each product in which I used the following code:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK('Products'!A2)), 'Products'!A2,"")
```

This gives me the entire product number list automatically in the **'Inventory'** sheet (I then fit the product name to the number using `INDEX-MATCH` functions). So now it's easy for me to write how much inventory I have for each product in the next coulmn.

Problem is, when I add a new product in the 'Products' sheet `(ex. #103 Brown triangle plate)` it will update the name and number of the product in the 'Inventory' sheet but the numbers I entered for the inventory won't move according to the product, so now the quantity is not aligned with the right product row.

So my question is how can I link the quantity to the product so they move together when a new product is entered (the product is not necessarily added in the last row, could be anywhere in the middle).

Maybe I should change the code I entered before (`=IF(NOT(ISBLANK('Products'!A2)), 'Products'!A2,"")`).

Comment: Why don't you use a proper database system rather than Excel? All your products will then have their own unique record, for which you can then do reporting - as you seem to be doing with you" inventory" sheet.

Comment: "I've reached a point where I'm quite sure I need VBA but I don't know VBA" - you're looking for help on the wrong place. We're helping each others by answering specific questions, but don't provide entire solutions doing somebody else's job.